# Read, scan, modify a text file and put modified text into a new file

Tags: java, .net, string, text

I've tried to read a text file and try to modify it. So many discussion that I got from StackOverflow, here is the content:

> NO 1025 0
>
> NO 1025 1
>
> OP 1026 0
>
> EndRow

The modified text file that I want:

> NO 0
>
> AND 1
>
> OP 0
>
> EndRow

I read some discussion topics about it, and then came the conclusion that I have to use the `.hasNextLine` method to check every line. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainConvert {

/**
 * @nahdiya
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File readNet = new File("testttt.net");
        FileReader readFileNet = new FileReader(readNet);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(readFileNet);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner("testttt.net");
        PrintWriter fileConvert = new PrintWriter("convertNet.txt");
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String check = scan.next();
            String checkLine = scan.nextLine();
            if (checkLine.contains("NO 1025")) {
                if(checkLine.contains("NO 1025")) {
                    fileConvert.println("AND "+check );
                } else if (checkLine.contains("OP 1026")) {
                    fileConvert.println("OP"+check);
                } else {
                    fileConvert.println(checkLine);}
                }
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        fileConvert.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I tried to run the class, an output message appeared like this:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at fileConvertSave.MainConvert.main(MainConvert.java:21)
```

The problem is:

```
PrintWriter fileConvert = new PrintWriter("convertNet.txt");
```

What is the problem with this line? I just want to modify the testttt.net file. `fileConvert` must be created as the new file. What is wrong with it?

Comment: I don't think that line is the problem. Please confirm that's line 21

Comment: String check = scan.next();
String checkLine = scan.nextLine(); is the problem

Answer (score 2):

**Edited: See the full solution at the bottom:**

The original problem that was yielding the error message was the Scanner trying to perform nextLine() on a line that wasn't there due to:

```
String check = scan.next(); 
String checkLine = scan.nextLine();
```

When you call:

```
while( scan.hasNextLine() )
```

there is a next line available. You then call:

```
scan.next();
```

At this point there might not be a "next line" available anymore. You then call:

```
scan.nextLine()
```

and boom.

removing the line

```
String check = scan.next();
```

should work.

**Edit:**

*Here is a solution to all the other parts of the problem...* It's basically a complete rewrite of what you've got, so please read all the code, learn what it does and try to understand it all! If in doubt, please read the documentation first before asking a question.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
PrintWriter writer = null;

try {                                    
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testttt.txt"));                       
    writer = new PrintWriter("convertNet.txt");            

    // setup the pattern that we want to find and replace in the input:
    // NB> this is a regex (or regular expression)
    // it means, find [space] then either 1025 or 1026 then [space]
    String patternToMatch = " (1025|1026) ";

    String inputLine = null;

    // while there are lines to read, read them one at a time:
    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        // create the outputLine which is the input line with our pattern
        // " 1025 " or " 1026 "  replaced by just a single space:
        String outputLine = inputLine.replaceFirst(patternToMatch, " ");

        // log the transformation for debugging purposes:                               
        System.out.println(inputLine + " -> " + outputLine);

        // write the outputLine to the output file:
        writer.println(outputLine);
    }
}  
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("file was not found: " + ex);        
} 
catch (IOException ex ) {
    System.out.println("io error: " + ex);
}
finally {
    try {
        if( reader != null ) reader.close();
        if ( writer != null ) writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("error closing file " + ex);
    }
}
```

Note that the finally block cleans up nicely even in the event there is an Exception. There's also a newer way to do this, that can make code a little shorter called try with resources:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: It works! Thank you, but....still, convertNet.txt doesn't contain anything. It's still a blank...file. However, i write String line = reader.readline() into the file, it works. And it contain something the same with the testttt.net, which is not the result that i want to...

Comment: Ok the original error you were getting was due to the Scanner, however I have now rewritten the whole thing with comments to meet your original requirements and explain how it works. Please read ALL the code and learn what each line does and why. If you have any doubts lookup the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your string does not look consistent i recommend you use regex if there are more strings like this and Bufferreader to read line, although i didn't use regex but this what i came up with,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File readNet = new File("testttt.net");
            FileReader readFileNet = new FileReader(readNet);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(readFileNet);

            PrintWriter fileConvert = new PrintWriter("convertNet.txt");
            String r = null;
            while ((r = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(r);
                if (r.equals("NO 1025 1")) {
                    fileConvert.println(r.replace(r, "AND 1"));

                } else if (r.contains("1025 0")) {
                    fileConvert.println(r.replaceAll("1025", ""));
                } else if (r.contains("1026")) {
                    fileConvert.println(r.replaceAll("1026", ""));
                } else {
                    fileConvert.println(r);
                }
            }

            reader.close();
            fileConvert.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Good Luck, i hope it helps you.

Comment: It seems that you replace the old ones directly. It works, thank you. But the thing is, the numbers behind **NO 1025** and **OP 1026** are not fixed numbers. They can change. So the pattern is like **NO 1025 X (X is any integer number from 1 to 16)**. I just want to change **"NO 1025"** and **"OP 1026"**, not the number behind them. This is why I used **next()** to scan the next word after space. Or do i get it wrong? This is the first time for me hear about regex, and i've done some little research about it, and it seems worth to try. Thanks for the information :) @Immanuel